# Changing oval fill in a sequence

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am new to programming.  I build rehabilitation equipment for older people and have retired so working at home. This is for a wheel chair user leg exercise mat.  I have made a layout in tkinter canvas but cannot change the fill in sequence (red and green) to show which feet to move and when.  The fill colour needs to be on for about 2 seconds for each foot, moving one foot at once.  My code to far is:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter 
#from time import sleep
import time

C = tkinter.Canvas(bg="blue", height=500, width=500)
oval1 = C.create_oval (171, 37.5, 196, 62.5, outline="white")#,     #fill="yellow")
oval2 = C.create_oval (304, 37.5, 329, 62.5, outline="white")#, #fill="yellow")
oval3 = C.create_oval (37.5, 137.5, 62.5, 162.5, outline="white")#, #fill="yellow")
oval4 = C.create_oval (437.5, 137.5, 462.5, 162.5, outline="white")#, #fill="yellow")
oval5 = C.create_oval (171, 237.5, 196, 262.5, outline="white")#, #fill="yellow")
oval6 = C.create_oval (304, 237.5, 329, 262.5, outline="white")#, #fill="yellow")
oval7 = C.create_oval (37.5, 337.5, 62.5, 362.5, outline="white")#, #fill="yellow")
oval8 = C.create_oval (437.5, 337.5, 462.5, 362.5, outline="white")#, #fill="yellow")
oval9 = C.create_oval (171, 437.5, 196, 462.5, outline="white")#, #fill="yellow")
oval10 = C.create_oval (304, 437.5, 329, 462.5, outline="white")#, #fill="yellow")
C.pack()
```

I have tried all I can but can't make it work. Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: don't just tell us what you've tried, _show_ us. Or, explain what you've researched. There are many examples of changing the color of canvas objects on this site and many others on the web.

Comment: have you tried using the `.after()` method? you can specify a time in milliseconds to wait and a function to call after that time.

Comment: Create a function (say Update) and call it using .after() as mentioned by Tadhg McDonald-Jensen. You can incorporate the changes required in this function after initialising it outside.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I need to make my question clearer and I will make a better attempt to include the code I am using. I have tried using After while etc but the program either stops or goes to the last screen. What I am using looks childish compared to other people's code and is very long. Childish is OK but long means long editing to make it suitable for people that have special requirements, and they will be the majority. I have used "sleep" to give pauses.
        The code so far, about 20% completed,;
from tkinter import *
import time
from time import sleep
import tkinter
import tkinter as tk
from time import *
class App(tk.Tk):
    def **init**(self):
        tk.Tk.**init**(self)
        self.frame_Light = tk.Canvas()
        self.light_on = True
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(bg="light blue", height=500, width=500)
        self.canvas.create_oval(171, 37.5, 196, 62.5, outline="black", tags="light1")#, #fill
        self.canvas.create_oval (304, 37.5, 329, 62.5, outline="black", tags="light2")#, #fill="yellow")
        self.canvas.create_oval (37.5, 137.5, 62.5, 162.5, outline="black", tags="light3")#, #fill="yellow")
        self.canvas.create_oval (437.5, 137.5, 462.5, 162.5, outline="black", tags="light4")#, #fill="yellow")
        self.canvas.create_oval (171, 237.5, 196, 262.5, outline="black", tags="light5")#, #fill="yellow")
        self.canvas.create_oval (304, 237.5, 329, 262.5, outline="black", tags="light6")#, #fill="yellow")
        self.canvas.create_oval (37.5, 337.5, 62.5, 362.5, outline="black", tags="light7")#, #fill="yellow")
        self.canvas.create_oval (437.5, 337.5, 462.5, 362.5, outline="black", tags="light8")#, #fill="yellow")
        self.canvas.create_oval (171, 437.5, 196, 462.5, outline="black", tags="light9")#, #fill="yellow")
        self.canvas.create_oval (304, 437.5, 329, 462.5, outline="black", tags="light10")#, #fill="yellow
        self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.draw_light()

```
def draw_light(self):
    for i in range(1): ## start
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light1", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light2", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light3", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light4", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="red")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="green")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light7", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light8", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light9", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light10", fill="white")        
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)    ### 1
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light1", fill="red")    
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)### 2
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light1", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="red")       
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)### 3
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light2", fill="green")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="red")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="white")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)### 4
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light2", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="red")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)### 5
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light9", fill="red")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)### 6
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light9", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="red")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)### 7
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light10", fill="green")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="red")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="white")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)### 8
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light10", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="red")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)### 9
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light1", fill="red")    
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)### 10
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light1", fill="red")       
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light2", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)### 11
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light9", fill="red")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light2", fill="green")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light1", fill="white")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)### 12
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light9", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light1", fill="red")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light2", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)### 13
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light10", fill="green")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light1", fill="red")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light2", fill="white")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)### 14
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light10", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light1", fill="red")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light2", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)### 15
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light2", fill="green")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light9", fill="red")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light1", fill="white")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)### 16
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light2", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light9", fill="red")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light10", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()            
        sleep(2) ### 17
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light9", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light1", fill="red")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light10", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)### 18
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light10", fill="green")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light9", fill="red")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light1", fill="white")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)### 19
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light10", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light9", fill="red")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light2", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)### 20
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light10", fill="green")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light9", fill="red")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light2", fill="white")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)### 21
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light9", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="red")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light10", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()            
        sleep(2) ### 22
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="green")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="red")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light10", fill="white")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2) ###########################################


        self.canvas.itemconfig("light3", fill="red")    
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light3", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="red")       
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light1", fill="red")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light1", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="red")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light2", fill="red")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light2", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="red")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light4", fill="red")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light4", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="red")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light4", fill="green")    
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="red")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="white")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light4", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="red")       
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light2", fill="green")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="red")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="white")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light2", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="red")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light1", fill="green")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="red")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="white")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light1", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="red")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light3", fill="green")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="red")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="white")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light3", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="red")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2) #####

        self.canvas.itemconfig("light7", fill="red")    
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light7", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="red")       
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light9", fill="red")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light9", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="red")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light10", fill="red")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light10", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="red")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light8", fill="red")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light8", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="red")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light8", fill="green")    
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="red")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="white")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light8", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="red")       
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light10", fill="green")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="red")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="white")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light10", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="red")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light9", fill="green")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="red")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="white")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light9", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="red")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light7", fill="green")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="red")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="white")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2)
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light7", fill="white")
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light5", fill="red")     
        self.canvas.itemconfig("light6", fill="green")
        self.canvas.update()
        sleep(2) ##### code so far
```

app = App()
app.mainloop()